# PixlUI not getting fonts in android

Tags: android

I am trying to use PixlUI and have custom fonts working with it. I am not able to get it working on Android Studio. I have followed every step on there site.

I still get

```
Asset not found: fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf (2 similar errors not shown)
```

assets/fonts folder has ttf files.

[image]

and I am using:

```
<com.neopixl.pixlui.components.textview.TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelattributetext"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Specification"
        android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector_listview"
        pixlui:copyandpaste="false"
        style="@style/TextRoboto.t1"
        pixlui:clearclipboardcontent="true"/>
```

And styles.xml has the follow

```
style name="TextRoboto.t1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="typeface">Roboto-Regular.ttf</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    </style>
```

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Asset not found: fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf (2 similar errors not shown)
```

If you get this error in the **Android Studio Layout Editor**, this is **normal**, please use PixlUI 1.1.0 and use the 23 target preview:

[image]
And so **all will be ok**

About Asset, be sure your asset folder is recognized by Android Studio (don't create folder by yourself) and put your fonts like this:

[image]
And in the XML style file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to get it correctly

Go to the (project folder)

1.Then **app>src>main**

2.Create folder **assets>fonts** into the **main folder**/Android studio can create it for you.

3.Put your **abc.ttf** into the fonts folder.

And then use it like

```
TextView tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Tv1);

Typeface myFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),  "fonts/abc.ttf");

tx.setTypeface(myFont);
```

**Or**

Go to **App>New>Folder>Assets Folder>Finish**

It will create Assets Folder Automatically for you and then Add a folder named as **Fonts** And their add your font **abc.ttf**

And follow the above Code.

**OR**

Follow this link and Do from a fresh start mayBe there would some problem in Path/Structure or something like that and Yes verify that the font you are using is in a correct format or is Valid.

[How to integrate your custom font in your Android app](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-custom-fonts-in-your-android-apps.html)

Hopefully this will work for you.Thanks!

Comment: Thanks.. I have already tried it. I get the following error: 

java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf
at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:190)

Comment: If you are working on Android Studio make sure your asset folder is under main and not res.Is that like that?

Comment: it is not insdie Res folder.

Comment: Give complete path here style="@style/TextRoboto.t1"

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by complete path?

Comment: Means assets/fonts/yourfont

Comment: Are you asking to put the full path in style.xml right?

Comment: Yeah...ypu should try once

Comment: Done. still the same.

Comment: I HAVE TO do some exercise for your problem and will get back to you after some time...Rather than commenting here lets make a chat room

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103400/discussion-between-mani-and-sanjana-nair).

Comment: You don't need specify path in style.xml